# Firefox doesn't switch controls in media-tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm building a custom html5-mediaplayer. I use custom controls, so when I create a media element (with JS) I first set it to controls = false; When going fullscreen with a video, I want to change the value of controls to true, so that they appear in fullscreen mode only. However, the object stays on false. It seems one cannot change the controls, once they are set.

Am I missing something? How can I change that value? All other browsers I've tried do that nicely (Chromium, Opera, Safari - Linux and MacOS). And all documentation I found said, that this should work.

The code in question is this, both are not working:

```
function fullscreen()
{
 document.getElementById("cbPlayer_fullscreen").blur(); //fullscreen-button
 var currentMedia = document.getElementById(currentMediaId);

 currentMedia.removeAttribute("controls");
 //currentMedia.controls = true;
 currentMedia.setAttribute("controls","controls");

 // go full-screen
 if (currentMedia.requestFullscreen) { currentMedia.requestFullscreen(); }
 else if (currentMedia.msRequestFullscreen) { currentMedia.msRequestFullscreen(); }
 else if (currentMedia.mozRequestFullScreen) { currentMedia.mozRequestFullScreen(); }
 else if (currentMedia.webkitRequestFullscreen) { currentMedia.webkitRequestFullscreen(); }
}
```

No errors in the console.

Thanks for any hints!

chris

...oh, you can see this thing in the wild here: https://musicchris.de/?page=media

Comment: On Firefox??? What OS do you use?

Comment: I take it, you didn't look with Firefox?

Comment: Indeed, however, can you try just setting the controls value on the video element, with true

Comment: I tried turning on the controls manually and it uses controls="true" not controls="controls"

Comment: No luck there! I've set it to `currentMedia.setAttribute("controls","true");` - no change. :(

Comment: Though I found in the documentations, that one can set it via `.controls = true;` OR `.setAttribute("controls","controls");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94560/discussion-between-olavi-sau-and-chris-blues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to actually call the fullscreen() function:

```
<a onclick="fullscreen()" class="cbPlayer_fullscreen" href="javascript:">
   <img style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px gray;" id="cbPlayer_fullscreen" class="cbPlayer_mediacontrols cbPlayer_fullscreen" src="cbplayer/pics/fullscreen.png" alt="fullscreen" title="fullscreen">
</a>
```

I also suggest you move your js to a separate file :)

Comment: Seems I need to run a big clean-up session on the entire code! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it would be a good idea, luckily most of your code is fairly clean just moving files mostly :)